# App Indexing: We can’t find the APK for Android app

Tags: android, google-search, deep-linking, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I am trying to do Android App Indexing. I followed all steps on [Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app). When I test the implementation, it says Google did not find App content associated with the URL.

APP URL:

android-app://com.package.name/http/www.example.com

Web URL `http://www.example.com`

Google can't find my APK even though APK is published. I allowed couple of days for indexing but nothing has changed. I associated my website with my app and verified that I am the owner on Google Search Console. I tried http and https with no luck.

What am I missing?